# Redis StringGet in Batch / Transaction?

Tags: c#, multithreading, optimization, redis

We have a Web Application which uses Redis for caching.

I have noticed some latency spikes when a Key with **200KB value** is accessed with almost concurrent requests (**Fiddler Shift + R** of the same request **20 - 50 times**).

Normal read time for the item is around **50ms**, but spikes to around **800ms.**

[image: spike]

I am thinking if there is a way to optimize this? Is there a way to use pipeline / batch for GET? Is it going to make some difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible? Maybe. The problem is, the requests you are seeing are not related, and do not know about each other. So to do *batching*, you would need to do something like:

1. Collect all keys to request from incoming requests.
2. Every n milliseconds issue a single redis `GET` for multiple keys.
3. Distribute results to all waiting callers.

This creates a lot of management overhead, and slows down requests.

Probably better would be to use an in-memory **[cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** to store results for some period of time, and reuse them for future requests.

That can still be tricky due to cases where a request comes in for a key that another request is currently fetching from redis. Can be hard to dedupe in-flight requests if you care about that kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks captncraig. In-memory cache idea sounds great. I am wondering why the Redis StringGet seems to spike up. I am thinking it might have something to do with requests fighting for access on the Connection.

Comment: With timings that bad, it feels like your redis instance is probably undersized or underpowered, but its hard to tell from here. Could be any number of networking factors or configurations.

Comment: 20-50 requests is really a tiny number for a redis instance. Even big requests on a small server should be faster than that.